# How to check if a variable exists in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, variables, exists

Is there a way to create a variable in jQuery / JavaScript if it not exists?

I've tried:

```
    if (moving.length<0) {
        moving=false;
    }

    if (moving=='undefined') {
        moving=false;
    }
```

But logically it all failes because the initial check on the variable is already undefined.

Hope you guys can help :)

---

### EDIT

First answer worked properly but my problems with this continue.

```
$.fn.animation = function() {
    if (typeof moving == 'undefined') {var moving = false;};

    if(moving===false){
        var moving=true;
        console.log('test');
    };      
};


$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() < scrollpos){
        elm.animation();
    }
    scrollpos=$(window).scrollTop();
});
```

In this setup 'test' gets constantly logged even if I log moving which is set to true the if still gets ignored.

So what I want to archive is that every time I scroll the element get checked if its already animated. If so, don't do the animation.

Basically a queue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Did you try

```
if (typeof moving == 'undefined') var moving = false;
```

In some cases I use

```
var moving = typeof moving == 'undefined' ? false : moving;
```

which is basically the same, but for me it's more readable in some cases to see that the variable is set, either to it's original value, or `false` if it's undeclared, but the first version is more common.

**EDIT:**

Here's how to detect scroll

```
var scrolled = false;

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    scrolled = true;
});

//later

if (scrolled) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: first solution worked properly, but im still having trouble to achive what i want. Basicly i execute a function on the window scroll event and it should set me a variable and if this variable is set i check for it and change it to true in the "if".

Comment: @StefanHövelmanns - added something to the answer, is that what you're trying to do ?

Comment: why not `var moving = moving || false` ?. I'm asking, @adeneo, I'd like to find out the difference with your solution

Comment: @steo - for this example, or any that's using a boolean only, it's the same thing, but for more complicated values there's a big difference in how bitwise and logical operators work, so I used a logical ternary condition here as it equals the logical `if` condition, and won't cause issues if other data types are used.

Comment: That said, I often use the bitwise OR myself, but you have to know what you're working with, and wether or not it will work as planned with bitwise operators.

Comment: Ok, so it depends on how complicated are values inside `variables`, right? I'm thinking about the common `pattern` of using `var app = app || {}` and commonly, `app` is not such a "simple" `variable`, that's why I'm asking. Thank you for clarification!

Comment: @steo - It's still a simple condition, app is either an object or not declared, and if it's the latter, you create a new object, so you know what you have to work with

Answer (score 4):

```
if( typeof moving === 'undefined' )
{
    var moving;

    moving = false;
}
```

Will work.